# Navbar toggle collapse doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with the header on my website. When I click the button to toggle the mobile menu on the *navbar* it "works" but the content doesn't appear.

I tried it on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lM8zFcgKl7) and it worked:

[image: preview on my site]

Comment: give link to your site please...

Comment: works absolutely fine for me in the mobile view of Bootply

Comment: http://www.hexaweb.it/clienti/noi/ check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `overflow: hidden` from `.headerp` or change to `overflow: visible`

collapsed menu is inside `.headerp` that have fixed height and `overflow: hidden`.

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
.headerp {
    height: 80px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```